# Isolated styled-components with @font-face

Tags: styled-components

I'm using https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components.

I'm trying to work out the best strategy for components that require `@font-face`. I want to make sure each component is independent of its context, so I'm defining `font-family` styles on each them. But if I use `injectGlobal` in multiple components, I get multiple `@font-face` rules for the same font.

Should I just define the `@font-face` rules in my `ThemeProvider` entry-point component and live with the fact that the desired font might not be loaded by the browser?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That's exactly why we made `injectGlobal`. If you take a look at our [docs](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/docs/api.md#injectglobal) they say:

> **We do not encourage the use of this. Use once per app at most, contained in a single file.** This is an escape hatch. Only use it for the rare `@font-face` definition or body styling.

So what I'd do is create a JS file called `global-styles.js` which contains this code:

```
// global-styles.js

import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';

injectGlobal`
  @font-face {
     font-family: 'My custom family';
     src: url('my-source.ttf');
  }
`
```

As you can see, all we do here is inject some global styling-in this case `@font-face`. The last thing necessary to make this work is to import this file in your main entry point:

```
// index.js

import './global-styles.js'

// More stuff here like ReactDOM.render(...)
```

This will mean your font-face is only injected once, but still all of your components have access to it with `font-family: 'My custom family'`!

Doing it this way will give you a flash-of-invisible-text (FOIT), but that has nothing to do with `styled-components`-it'd be the same if you were using vanilla CSS. To get rid of the FOIT requires a more advanced font loading strategy rather than just `@font-face`ing.

Since this has nothing to do with `styled-components`, I highly recommend watching these two Front End Center episodes to learn more about how to best do this: ["Crafting Web Font Fallbacks"](https://frontend.center/ep8-crafting-webfont-fallbacks) and ["The Fastest Webfont Loader in the West"](https://frontend.center/ep11-the-fastest-webfont-loader-in-the-west)!

Comment: The new doc link should be https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#injectglobal

Comment: The `injectGlobal` API was removed and replaced by `createGlobalStyle` in styled-components v4.

Comment: Is there a way to inject a global font face in styled v4 without using a react component to load it in? We're producing a web component and would like the font to be loaded before the component is placed on the page.

Comment: @coppereyecat For me, this is the solution! "1. Group repainting": https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/js-web-fonts.html#1.-group-repaints

Comment: @Alexandre we ended up making a fontLoader function that preloaded fonts with `document.createElement('link')` for each font, followed by a `document.createElement('style')` that includes a CSS snippet defining them, which runs when our script is included on the page rather than when our component is loaded. It doesn't directly use `styled` at all, but the fonts are available for `styled` later.

Answer (score 16):

And on the other side of the same coin in Chrome:

do not use @font-face inside `injectGlobal` if using e.g. react-router.
You will get re-paint of all of you app on each newly loaded route.
And this is why:
[image]

Same font-files downloaded on each new route.
As soon as you include font-face in a separate `.css` file - problem solves as stated in the last comment in [this github issue](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1593).

Comment: What about placing `injectGlobal` outside react-router?
I use `injectGlobal` even outside `ReactDOM.render()`, i.e. on the very top level of the application and I don't get fonts loaded for each route navigation.

Comment: @Oleh how did you do that? Moved injectGlobal at the top - still getting fonts reloaded

Comment: Probably this is something browser specific, since Edge and Firefox don't load they font each time I navigate with route, even more the don't load the font on refresh page as well. Chrome does load the font each time... So seems to be a chrome engine issue

Comment: @Oleh, yes i forgot to mention that this is a chrome specific issue)

Answer (score 11):

**injectGlobal** is deprecated. Use **createGlobalStyle**

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components'

export const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`  
  body {
    font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;

    h1 {
      font-weight: 800;
      font-size: 36px;

    p {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
  }
`;
```

Then you can use it in your App.js:

```
import { GlobalStyle } from './styles/global'

class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <>
          <GlobalStyle/>
          <Container/>
        </>
      </ThemeProvider>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I still get all the fonts reloaded even with `createGlobalStyle`

Answer (score 1):

I agree

I get reloaded with

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import { silver } from 'shared-components/themes/colors';

export default createGlobalStyle`
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Proxima Nova";
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url("/static/media/fonts/proxima_nova/ProximaNova_300.otf");
    }
```

and react create app